# What do these forward currents at specified wattages mean?

Tags: voltage, led, current, watts, specifications

An LED I'm looking at has various specs listed that I can't make heads nor tails of. It is listed as a "3W LED" supporting a 2.5V minimum and 3.6V voltage. However, "Forward voltage" is listed as 3.4V-3.6V. Which makes me wonder what the 2.5V minimum means.

Also, it lists "Forward current" as "350mA@1W 700mA@3W". Now, if I take those values I get respectively 1W/0.35A = 2.85V and 3W/0,7A = 4.28V - totally different ranges than listed under the supported voltages. Besides, I would imagine that a 3W LED running at 3.6V would have a forward current of 833mA. Why are they listing two of them?

Is this just a mistake on the seller's specifications or am I missing something?

Comment: As always, please link to the datasheet.

Comment: That parameters are not accurate, mostly from unknown manufacturers. Similar devices from known manufacturers with datasheet has another values, like 2W, etc.

Comment: @Transistor There is no datasheet, this is the data available to me.

Comment: "No datasheet? No sale!"  You might find [LEDs and binning](http://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/variations-vf-binning/) relevant.

Comment: I mean, that "always get a datasheet" rule is great if you're not on a budget but sometimes components like these are the only affordable ones available. Too bad, I'll have to look further or just take a chance on them I guess.

Comment: No, incorrect, @Bas - you should always choose components that have a data sheet unless you have a profoundly good reason (that I can't think of).

Answer (score 0):

As others suggest - a LED without a datasheet is a black box.

That said, you might cull some information from a decently specified 3W LED made by **Broadcom** on its data sheet: Their device: **ASM3-SxDx-xxxxH-DS100**

Figure 7 below shows voltage and current relationship for a few different colour LEDs. The **royal blue** or **cool white** LEDs are somewhat similar to your meager specs. Figure 7 would be pulse-measured so that ambient temperature remains at 25 degrees C.
Figure 12 shows how temperature modifies forward voltage. It is very likely that your LED will need a heat sink to keep cool - since you have no specs, how much cooling you need is unknown. Your LED might do for just *foolin' around*, or for running much less than the limits shown here.
Most LEDs are best driven with a current source, rather than a voltage source.
[image: Broadcom 3W LED current/voltage/temperature graphs]